# Pricing Plan of Microsoft Custom Speech Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform

I have been looking into Microsoft Custom Speech Recognition(CRIS)and I had a query with regards to its pricing plan.
On their pricing plan, Microsoft has mentioned the following details for S0 plan:

Speech Translation - $2.50 per hour
Speech to Text - $1 per hour
Speech to Text with Custom Speech Model - $1.40 per hour
Speech Endpoint Hosting - $40.00/model/month

My question may be amateurish since I have just begun to look into this but when they mention per hour, does this count the hours even when I am not hitting my speech endpoint, i.e does the pricing start as and when I create my resource?

For example - If I have created my Speech to Text service and have only hit it once in 24 hours, will I be charged only for the time it took to convert my speech to text or will I be charged 24 * $1 regardless of the usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get charged for what you use, not the up-time of the service.

Comment: Thank you @Ali Heikal. So, the hourly rates are based on the number of hits to the endpoint and the time it takes for the response? Even if it has been, say 2 days since the service has been started?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It is essentially based on the duration of the audio files you’re sending...

Comment: So, I can fit as many utterances as I want to in an hour and that would cost me $1 for the speech-to-text conversion.  Understood. Thank you very much, @Ali Heikal.

Comment: "So, I can fit as many utterances as I want to in an hour and that would cost me $1 for the speech-to-text conversion" < the `hours` notion here is the cumulated length of your audio items. That's not "sending as many files as I want during 1 hour of time"

Comment: Just like I mentioned in my previous reply and @NicolasR mentioned in his comment, it is the sum of the duration of the audio files you're sending, but not sending as many files as you want in 1 hour!

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I did not phrase that sentence well enough. My apologies. Thank you, @Nicolas R

Answer (score 1):

the real-time of you audio is measured. If you want to transcribe 20 minutes of audio, this is what you are getting charged for. Be aware - if you try to transcribe 20 minutes of silence, it is a 20 minute charge...

Comment: Yes, I understand that. To say it loosely, its a "Pay as you go" service where I will only be charged as per my usage. Thank you, @wolfma